# No variable substituion in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would use environment file to set some variables in a docker compose file, to choose what environment to use : dev, qualif, prod, ... But variable substitution doesn't work as I expected. Here an extract of my docker compose file :

```
version: '3.4'
x-propertyfile: &propertyfile dev.env

services:
    registry:
        image: sensor-registry
        env_file: *propertyfile
        container_name: ${REGISTRY_NAME}
        ...
    other-services:
        ...
```

And my dev.env file :

```
REGISTRY_NAME=registry
... other values
```

But when I launch my docker-services with

```
docker-compose -f compose-file.yml up
```

I got the message :

```
WARNING: The REGISTRY_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

I try to set env_file without custom property :

```
services:
    registry:
        image: sensor-registry
        env_file: dev.env
        container_name: ${REGISTRY_NAME}
```

That does not work. Idem if I directly set my variable :

```
services:
    registry:
        image: sensor-registry
        environment:
            - REGISTRY_NAME: registry
        container_name: ${REGISTRY_NAME}
```

But if I use the default env file (.env), that works. I can launch my services with :

```
cat dev.env > .env && docker-compose -f composefile.yml up
```

But I want understand why variable substitution does not work with env_file. What does I wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **env_file** key (likewise for the  **environment** key) is used to set environment variables for use inside the container only.

For variables intended to be interpolated within the docker-compose.yml file, they have to come from the host machine in one of the following ways:

- As exported environment variable(s)
- As environment variable(s) set when calling `docker-compose up` (e.g: `FOO=bar docker-compose up`)
- As environment variable(s) specified in a special file called **.env**

So then, when you use in your docker-compose.yml file:

```
env_file: dev.env
```

The environment variables defined in the **dev.env**  file will only be availabe from inside the container, not in the docker-compose.yml file.

The two relevant extracts from the documentation are:

From [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file):

> You can pass multiple environment variables from an external file through to a service’s containers with the ‘env_file’ option, just like with docker run --env-file=FILE ...:

and further down:

> You can set default values for any environment variables referenced in the Compose file, or used to configure Compose, in an environment file named .env

The later may be a bit confusing, but it means that if FOO and BAR are specified in an **.env** file, you can do this in the docker-compose file:

```
one-service:
    environment:
      - FRAMEWORK=${FOO}


other-service:
    image: bash:4
    container_name: ${BAR}
```

and also have in that file special environment variables (**COMPOSE_***) to configure Docker-compose.

Following that, and as a side effect, If you use in your compose file:

```
env_file: .env
```

The same set of environment variables will be equally available inside the container and in the docker-compose file.

An alternative to the solution you have found for configuring multiple environments is to use and merge (combine) multiple compose files.

To illustrate that, here is a semi-hypothetical example where you create the following docker compose files:

- docker-compose.core.yml
- docker-compose.dev.yml
- docker-compose.test.yml

that you specify as below:

**docker-compose.core.yml:**

```
services:
    web:
      image: nginx
      volumes:
        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-availables/default
      networks:
        - backend
      dns:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 9.9.9.9
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
```

**docker-compose.dev.yml:**

```
services:
    web:
      container_name: dev_server
      ports:
        - 8080:80
        - 8443:443
```

**docker-compose.test.yml:**

```
services:
    web:
      container_name: test_server
```

Then on dev:

```
$  docker-compose -f docker-compose.core.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d web
```

On test:

```
$  docker-compose -f docker-compose.core.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml up -d web
```

The documentation for that feature is in [Overview of Docker compose CLI](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--f-to-specify-name-and-path-of-one-or-more-compose-files)

If you don't want to type all those file names you can set them in a special environment variable on the host:

on dev:

```
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.core.yml:docker-compose.dev.yml
```

on test:

```
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.core.yml:docker-compose.test.yml
```

The documentation for **COMPOSE_FILE** can be found in [Compose CLI environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/)

Hope it helps.